# Find gmail account associated with Wordpress google cloud project

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I had multiple gmail accounts for project hosting on google cloud (Bad management). Now after more than 1 year I want to remove the project from google cloud.

I am struggling with finding the **Cloud project ID** as I am unable to find the gmail account associated with that project.

Project is basic Wordpress blog site - successfollows.com
and I dont have wordpress username and password either.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to http://www.successfollows.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword and try your emails one-by-one. If it gives "ERROR: There is no user registered with that email address." error, skip to the next email. When you at last enter correct email, it will give success message about "Email has been sent".

Comment: The email could not be sent.
Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function.

Comment: hmm it means your website hasn't had email sending feature before. do you have an access to your filesystem or mysql?

Comment: Problem is I cant get to those data as I am not sure which gmail account has that rights. I tried all known accounts but none worked.

Comment: The email which gives "The email could not be sent" error is exactly that you are looking for. Because if to type different error, you will get "ERROR: There is no user registered with that email address."  message. if you get  "The email could not be sent" , it means that email exists in that WP website as admin email.